# What is causing calls to sharepoint server vti_bin\sites.asmx

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0

We are looking at logs on our sharepoint site (wss 3.0) and see a call to this web service from several PC's.

The calls apprear very regular every 5 mins, when the PC is on.

Anyone know what is causing this?

According to the IIS log the user agent is

> The agent in the iis log is: Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+HO32602;+HO32600;+HO32501;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alot of Office programs such as Outlook, Word, Excel and Access can comunicate with SharePoint for different reasons and on different services.

In outlook a user might have connected a calendar, contact list or task list to the site, or users might be using Outlook to book meetings in SharePoint meeting sites.

Other office programs can also be connected to SharePoint in different ways, so this might explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Office 2007 and above will make calls to SharePoint to determine what sites the user has access.  Office then creates shortcuts to these sites on the client.  These sites can then be accessed in Office via open/save dialogs under 'My SharePoint Sites'